# DSM and buildings height

Tags: dem, elevation, envi

How can I create a Digital Surface Model in order to collect the height of buildings and what's exactly needed to create a Digital Surface Model?

Any software provide creating it (ENVI or PCI preferred)

I have a stereo pair satellite images and tried ENVI but I didnt know exactly what I need to have and the requirement to get the perfect DSM

Mostly used software for me is Arcgis and am not used to Imagery

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, can you provide more details of what you have tried already?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: i just edited it the question i tried Envi any help will be appreciated especially cause i dont know what the requirement needed to create the dsm and i search alot

Comment: Using ENVI what precisely did you try and where did you get stuck?  If you hit a dead end asking about that and want to ask about PCI then in a separate question will be the way to do so.

Comment: am sorry am not good in explaining my bad , but mostly what i need is that i dont know whats the exactly requirement i need to have in order to make a dsm generally ( i dont know if  the requirement change from software to another thats why i put envi or pci )